# why (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse() method returning status code 200 for Error Page?

Tags: c#

(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse() method returning status code 200 for Error Page instead of status code 400.

The Url is

http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/zh-cht/office365-smallbusinesses/hh911992.aspx

when we open the above url in browser, it showing error page with message "We're sorry! We were unable to service your request."

But the status code return from webresponse is 200.

I code wriiten for it is

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loclink);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
code = (int)response.StatusCode;
```

please help me to track this type of url?

Comment: Have you checked to see if that page isn't a "regular" page that's being displayed in the event that the server hits an error 400?

Comment: That's a custom error page. If you inspect it with Fiddler, you'll notice that the result is a 200 indeed. The *error* is a human interpretation

Comment: Ah I might aswell post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It feels wrong, to be honest. I've been there too and was equally confused.

It's a so-called "soft error page". It's because the webserver redirects you to that page when it hits an error instead of transmitting the actual error page.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this server doesn't force status code for error pages, so you could try to check that this page contains special elements/words.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up against this whilst trying to verify a security metrics issue with one of our sites.

The reason you get a 200 response and not a 400 is because the error is being handled by the server gracefully, rather than showing you the actual error page, it's catching it and redirecting you to a friendly "An unexpected error has occurred" page which will obviously show a 200 response.

To get the actual error code you can try requesting the page in [Telnet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279466) via:

`GET /zh-cht/office365-smallbusinesses/hh911992.aspx`